# Cannot read case-sensitive Glue table backed by Parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, parquet, aws-glue-data-catalog

Spark version: 2.4.2 on Amazon EMR 5.24.0

I have a Glue Catalog table backed by S3 Parquet directory. The Parquet files have case-sensitive column names (like `lastModified`). It doesn't matter what I do, I get lowercase column names (`lastmodified`) when reading the Glue Catalog table with Spark:

```
for {
  i <- Seq(false, true)
  j <- Seq("NEVER_INFER", "INFER_AND_SAVE", "INFER_ONLY")
  k <- Seq(false, true)
} {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", i)
    .config("spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode", j)
    .config("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", k)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.sql

  val df = sql("""SELECT * FROM ecs_db.test_small""")
  df.columns.foreach(println)
}
```

[1] https://medium.com/@an_chee/why-using-mixed-case-field-names-in-hive-spark-sql-is-a-bad-idea-95da8b6ec1e0
[2] https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html

Answer (score 2):

## Edit

The below solution is incorrect.

1. Glue Crawlers are not supposed to set the `spark.sql.sources.schema.*` properties, but Spark SQL should. The default in Spark 2.4 for `spark.sql.hive.caseSensitiveInferenceMode` is `INFER_AND_SAVE` which means that Spark infers the schema from the underlying files and alters the tables to add the `spark.sql.sources.schema.*` properties to `SERDEPROPERTIES`. In our case, Spark failed to do so, because of a `IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string` exception which is caused because the Hive database class instance has an empty `locationUri` property string. This is caused because the Glue database does not have a Location property [image]. After the schema is saved, Spark reads it from the table.
2. There could be a way around this, by setting `INFER_ONLY`, which should only infer the schema from the files and not attempt to alter the table `SERDEPROPERTIES`. However, this doesn't work because of a Spark bug, where the inferred schema is then lowercased (see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c1b6fe479649c482947dfce6b6db67b159bd78a3/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala#L284)).

---

## Original solution (incorrect)

This bug happens because the Glue table's `SERDEPROPERTIES` is missing two important properties:

- `spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts`
- `spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0`

To solve the problem, I had to add those two properties via the Glue console (couldn't do it with `ALTER TABLE …`)

I guess this is a bug with Glue crawlers, which do not set these properties when creating the table.